# dplyr mutate specific columns by evaluating lookup cell value

Tags: r, dplyr, eval

I have explored various options using quosures, symbols, and evaluation, but I can't seem to get the right syntax. Here is an example dataframe.

```
data.frame("A" = letters[1:4], "B" = letters[26:23], "C" = letters[c(1,3,5,7)], "D" = letters[c(2,4,6,8)], "pastecols" = c("B, C","B, D", "B, C, D", NA))
  A B C D pastecols
1 a z a b      B, C
2 b y c d      B, D
3 c x e f   B, C, D
4 d w g h      <NA>
```

Now suppose I want to paste values from different columns based on the lookup string in pastecols, and I always want to include column A. This is my desired result:

```
  A B C D pastecols  result
1 a z a b      B, C   a z a
2 b y c d      B, D   b y d
3 c x e f   B, C, D c x e f
4 d w g h      <NA>       d
```

Ideally this could be done in dplyr. This is the closest I have gotten:

```
x %>% mutate(result = lapply(lapply(str_split(pastecols, ", "), c, "A"), na.omit))
  A B C D pastecols     result
1 a z a b      B, C    B, C, A
2 b y c d      B, D    B, D, A
3 c x e f   B, C, D B, C, D, A
4 d w g h      <NA>          A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `pmap` to do a similar thing. `pmap` can be used to effectively work on dataframes by row by capturing each row as a named vector; you can then get the desired column names for indexing as `cols` by selecting them with `["pastecols"]`.

Most of the anonymous function syntax is not `tidyverse` stuff, but just basic R stuff. To walk through it:

1. Pass the dataframe as the list to the `.l` argument of `pmap_chr`. Remember that dataframes are lists of columns!
2. Capture all the `...` arguments with `c(...)`. Basically we are calling each row of the dataframe as arguments to the function; now `row` is a named vector containing the row. Note that if you have list-columns this will break, (but so will a lot of other things here so I assume there aren't any...)
3. We can get the values of `row` that we want from `row["pastecols"]`, but we need to turn  (say) `"B, C"` into `c("A", "B", "C")` to do that. This next line just adds the `"A"`, replaces missing values with `"A"`, splits into pieces if there are any, and then indexes back down into the list. The `[[` part is just how you do `list[[1]]"` in a pipe chain, it's the prefix form of the operator. You need this because `str_split` returns a list and we just want the vector.
4. Use this `cols` vector to get the desired values from `row` and return it, collapsed into a length 1 character vector!

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble("A" = letters[1:4], "B" = letters[26:23], "C" = letters[c(1,3,5,7)], "D" = letters[c(2,4,6,8)], "pastecols" = c("B, C","B, D", "B, C, D", NA))

tbl %>%
  mutate(result = pmap_chr(
    .l = .,
    .f = function(...){
      row <-  c(...)
      cols <- row["pastecols"] %>% str_c("A, ", .) %>% replace_na("A") %>% str_split(", ") %>% `[[`(1)
      vals <- row[cols] %>% str_c(collapse = ", ")
      return(vals)
    }
  ))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   A     B     C     D     pastecols result    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     
#> 1 a     z     a     b     B, C      a, z, a   
#> 2 b     y     c     d     B, D      b, y, d   
#> 3 c     x     e     f     B, C, D   c, x, e, f
#> 4 d     w     g     h     <NA>      d
```

Created on 2018-12-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This approach appears to be almost 5X faster than your suggestion using gather. Bonus points because I have been trying to learn new functionality in purrr! Do you mind explaining what is happening in your function definition within pmap_chr? Specifically, the function(...), c(...) and the %>% `[[`(1).

Comment: Added some explanation. I suspect that this could be made faster if it is currently still too slow by doing the `cols` part outside of `pmap` since `str_c` and `str_split` are vectorised, but it would require some shuffling around of code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was familiar with the list operator, I had just never seen it in a pipe chain like that. As for the ellipsis, that is something I have only seen in function documentation, glad I know how to use it effectively now!

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution but gets the job done with just base R. If column `A` never shows up in `pastecols` you can remove `unique()` from the code.

```
for(r in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  df$result[r] <- paste(
                    df[r, na.omit(unique(c("A", unlist(strsplit(df$pastecols[r], ", ")))))],
                    collapse = " "
                  )
}
df

  A B C D pastecols  result
1 a z a b      B, C   a z a
2 b y c d      B, D   b y d
3 c x e f   B, C, D c x e f
4 d w g h      <NA>       d
```

Data -

```
df <- data.frame(
  "A" = letters[1:4], 
  "B" = letters[26:23], 
  "C" = letters[c(1,3,5,7)], 
  "D" = letters[c(2,4,6,8)], 
  "pastecols" = c("B, C","B, D", "B, C, D", NA), stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way that doesn't rely on iterating functions in the `apply` or `map` families, if you would prefer to avoid them, and tries to leverage the `tidyr` side of the `tidyverse`. The approach is basically to expand the dataframe with `gather` and `separate_rows` into each combination of `pastecols` and actual columns, and then `filter` so we only keep the ones that match for each `rowid`. Once we have that, we can `group_by` and `summarise` to bring it back to one row per `rowid`. There is a bunch of housekeeping to deal with the fact that you always have column `A`, and note that I leave `A` in the output `pastecols`, but you can remove that if you want to.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble("A" = letters[1:4], "B" = letters[26:23], "C" = letters[c(1,3,5,7)], "D" = letters[c(2,4,6,8)], "pastecols" = c("B, C","B, D", "B, C, D", NA))

tbl %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  mutate(
    pastecols = str_c("A, ", pastecols),
    pastecols = if_else(is.na(pastecols), "A", pastecols)
  ) %>%
  gather(colname, value, -pastecols, -rowid) %>%
  separate_rows(pastecols) %>%
  filter(pastecols == colname) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  summarise(
    pastecols = str_c(pastecols, collapse = ", "),
    result = str_c(value, collapse = ", ")
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   rowid pastecols  result    
#>   <int> <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1     1 A, B, C    a, z, a   
#> 2     2 A, B, D    b, y, d   
#> 3     3 A, B, C, D c, x, e, f
#> 4     4 A          d
```

Created on 2018-12-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I like that this example sticks to the tidyverse side of things. I think I was trying to get too creative with quosures and such when gather and separate_rows are perfect for the job. I do worry about computation time for how I will be applying this in practice. Simple for the toy example, but the data I will be applying this to has 15 "pastecols" and ~6M rows. I'll have to try it out, but I imagine I may run into some memory overflow errors even with the beefy server I am using.